# How to obtain an orphan boolean xml value from a string

Tags: php, xml, arrays, string, curl

I'm working with an API which is returning some XML data that I'm unable to obtain.

When a login has been successful the session key becomes authenticated and the API returns the the boolean value 'true'.

This is formatted as follows:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. 
document tree is shown below.
<boolean xmlns="http://tessiturasoftware.com/">true</boolean>
```

Where other XML data has been formatted with more of a nested structure I've been able to use the following PHP to extract the data

```
$prodresponse = curl_exec($getproductions);
    if(curl_errno($getproductions))
{
echo 'Curl error: Unable to obtain session ID ' . curl_error($getproductions);
}

else{

$xmlContent =  simplexml_load_string($prodresponse);
echo $prodresponse;
foreach($xmlContent->xpath('//Production')as$prod){
$prodid= $prod->prod_season_no;
echo "<form action='GetProductionDetail.php' method='GET'>";
echo "<h1>".$prod->prod_desc." </h1> <input type='submit' value='Book Now'>
<input type='hidden' name='prodid' value=$prodid /></form>";
}
}
```

However when I attempt to use the following to return the boolean value and move to the account details page, no data is returned

```
$response2 = curl_exec($login);

$xmlContent = simplexml_load_string($response2);

if(curl_errno($login))
{
echo 'Curl error: Unable to login ' . curl_error($login);
}

else {
echo 'test';
foreach($xmlContent->xpath('boolean') as $bool) {
    echo $bool;
    echo 'test';
}
if ($bool=='true'){
echo'test';
header("Location: GetAccountDetails.php");
}
}
```

Please could someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, whether it's to do with the simplexml_load_string or whether it would help to create a simpleXMLObject etc...?

Thanks

Caspian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML has a namespace definition. So the "real/internal" name of the element is `{http://tessiturasoftware.com/}:boolean`. To fetch this element without ignoring the namespace, you need to register a prefix for it. SimpleXML has the method `registerXpathNamespace()` for that. After that you can use the prefix as an alias for the namespace string. If you register `tess` the element can be addressed as `tess:boolean`.

I prefer DOM because it allows me to do more complex Xpath, like casting the result to string and compare it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<boolean xmlns="http://tessiturasoftware.com/">true</boolean>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('tess', 'http://tessiturasoftware.com/');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/tess:boolean) = "true"')
);
```

Program Output

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number= getResources().getInteger(R.integer.yourNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get that to work.
I also tried getResources().getBoolean() and tried to echo out the value but was unsuccessful.